# Repeat Program in Xcode - C++

Tags: c++

The program is supposed to repeat after the user enters incorrect data for hours, minutes, seconds.

I can't get programs to loop on Xcode.

Example:

user enters invalid data for hours, minutes, and seconds.
Program displays "invalid data", and then asks the user if they would like to repeat the program, if the user enters "y or Y", the program asks the user to enter the time again.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct Time
{
    int hours ;
    int seconds;
    int minutes;
};

void getTime(Time &time);
bool isTimeValid(Time &time);
void addOneSecond(Time &time);
void displayTime(Time &time);

const int MAX_HOURS = 23;
const int MAX_MINS = 59;
const int MAX_SECS = 59;

int main()
{
    Time time;
    getTime(time);
    isTimeValid(time);
    addOneSecond(time);
    displayTime(time);
    return 0;
}
void getTime(Time &time)
{
    cout << "Enter the time in \"military time\", (24-hour format), in"
    << " the following order:\nHH:MM:SS, (Hours, Minutes, Seconds).\n\n";
    cout << "Hours: ";
    cin >> time.hours;
    cout << "Minutes: ";
    cin >> time.minutes;
    cout << "Seconds: ";
    cin >> time.seconds;
    cout << endl << endl;
}
bool isTimeValid(Time &time)
{
    bool answer = ' ';

    if (((time.hours >= 0) && (time.hours <= MAX_HOURS)) &&
        ((time.minutes >= 0) && (time.minutes <= MAX_MINS)) &&
        ((time.seconds >= 0) && (time.seconds <= MAX_SECS)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid Time.\n\n";
        return false;
    }

    cout << "Do it again? (Y/N)";
    cin >> answer;
    do
    {
        getTime(time);
        isTimeValid(time);
        addOneSecond(time);
        displayTime(time);

    } while(toupper(answer) == 'T' );
}
void addOneSecond(Time &time)
{
    time.seconds++;

    if (time.seconds > MAX_SECS)
    {
        time.seconds = 0;
        time.minutes++;
    }

}
void displayTime(Time &time)
{
    cout.fill('0');
    cout << "After adding one second, the time is " << setw(2) << time.hours
    << ":" << setw(2) << time.minutes << ":" << setw(2)
    << time.seconds << ".\n\n";

}
```

Comment: `} while(toupper(answer) == 'T' );` should that be `} while(toupper(answer) == 'Y');` instead?

Comment: You declare `answer` as a `bool`, try to save a `char` into it, but then use a `'T'` to check against its value even though you expected a `Y/N` from the user!

Comment: ok, so I changed it to char answer = ' '; and I changed the while statement to == 'Y'. it still won't work